# no se como terminar esta parte del codigo

Tags: java, netbeans, bucle-for, jtable

Lo que necesito hacer, es acumular las cantidades de las variables "cantidad, mt2,mtlineales"para después mostrarlas en otra clase(ventanadatos)y no se cómo hacerlo o cómo terminar el for para que funcione.
Además en la ejecución me da el error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2" según la cantidad de filas que se ingresan en el jTable. Desde ya muchas gracias.
Este es el código

```
for (int i = 0; i <= jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {
        float sumacant;
        float sumaalto;
        float sumaancho;
        sumacant = (int) Float.parseFloat(modelo.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
        sumaalto = (int) Float.parseFloat(modelo.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
        sumaancho = (int) Float.parseFloat(modelo.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
       
        cantidad = (int) sumacant;
        mt2 = (int) (sumaalto * sumaancho * cantidad);
        mtlineales = (int) ((sumaalto + sumaancho) * (2 * cantidad));
        
        ventanadatos.jl_mt2.setText(String.valueOf(mt2));
        ventanadatos.jl_mt_lineales.setText(String.valueOf(mtlineales));
        ventanadatos.jl_cantidad.setText(String.valueOf(cantidad));
    }
```

Comment: `i < jTable1.getRowCount()`. `getRowCount()` te dice cuantas filas hay, si tienes 2 filas devolverá un 2... pero si tu comprobación es `i <= 2`, estarás comprobando **TRES** índices, 0, 1 y 2. Obviamente solo tienes dos filas, la 0 y la 1, recuerda que los índices en java empiezan por 0 siempre!

Comment: excelente gracias, eso me solucionó el error, ahora me queda terminar el for, que no se como hacer todavía, si tienen sugerencias, muchas gracias.

Comment: Aquí no trabajamos con sugerencias, si no con errores. No saber hacer una cosa significa que tienes que seguir investigando e intentándolo :)